# Можно ли установить для спрайта прозрачность?

Tags: c++, sfml

```
objImage.loadFromFile(nameOfObject + "/Texture.png");
objTexture.loadFromImage(objImage);
objSprite.setTexture(objTexture);
```

Спрайт содержит картинку, ее нужно сделать полупрозрачной.
Видел как это делается с установкой цвета, но цвет на нее мне устанавливать не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

```
objImage.createMaskFromColor(Color::Black, 0);
```

[sf::Image::createMaskFromColor](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Image.php#a22f13f8c242a6b38eb73cc176b37ae34)

Можете в ручную добавить прозрачность, используйте соответствующие сайты/программы.

Answer (score 1):

> но цвет на нее мне устанавливать не нужно.

Вы можете установить цвет не на саму картинку, а на "спрайт":

```
objSprite.setColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 127));
```

так же можете поиграться с разнообразными режимами смешивания.

Есть возможность "прицепить" шейдер:

```
sf::Shader shader; 

const std::string fragmentShader =
    R"xxx(
        uniform sampler2D texture;
        uniform float opacity;

        void main()
        {
            vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
            gl_FragColor = pixel * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, opacity);
        }
    )xxx";

if (!shader.loadFromMemory(fragmentShader, sf::Shader::Fragment))
{
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

float opacity = 0.5f;
shader.setUniform("texture", sf::Shader::CurrentTexture);
shader.setUniform("opacity", opacity);

//game loop:
wnd.draw(objSprite, &shader);
```